# Windows XP will not connect to WPA2

Tags: networking, windows-xp

I'm using a Windows XP SP3 laptop. I am having troubles connecting to a WPA2 network. The laptop will connect fine to my WPA router, but will not connect to the WPA2 one. It hangs at the "Getting network type... Windows is trying to connect to this network..." message.

Comment: I stepped on such issues and it always turn out that it isn't XP but outdated WiFi adapter that cant handle WPA2

Comment: works from linux

Comment: If it works under linux then try to find kb893357 and reinstall it(actually it should be part of SP3). BTW, are you using some third party WiFi software (it usually comes together with WiFi card)? Just to narrow an issue, try to barrow from somebody some new USB based WiFi adapter and check if it would work with WPA2. This way you can find offender - either it is XP or WiFi driver

Comment: @Alex no third party software, i'll try the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [SkiRac3rDud3's suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1165299/648246) didn't help me on my machine, installing updated drivers did.

**Note: these steps are for the Atheros AR5004G.**

If anyone would like to know the full steps I did to solve the problem:

1. Get the Atheros driver, from here: http://web.archive.org/web/20070304080900/http://seth.kvalitne.cz/atheros/atheros400167.zip
2. Install it, but make sure that you do not install the "Client Utilities". They install a GINA module that will prevent the Welcome screen from working.
3. Try to connect to a WPA2 network! It works!

Comment: meh, you should be familiar enough with how things work on the network to know that a link only answer isn't much good. Granted, I didn't get *that* much out of reading the blog either. Useful information would be things like `I installed the driver without the “client utilities” (which were useless anyway).` and perhaps the exact version that worked

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ok, I just updated the answer

Comment: On Acer Aspire 5720G i install the latest intel wireless driver and WPA2 become working! Thank you for advise!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the network card you are using?

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/53df3c3d-a360-447f-879b-abad30bd8175/wpa2-in-windows-xp-sp3?forum=itproxpsp

Comment: didn't help me here

Comment: however, updating the drivers did, so I'll give you an upvote.